Trouble Determining X or Y Translation in SVG Transform Attribute with Internet Explorer
d3.select(me.svg.selectAll(".groupedbar")[0][0]).attr("transform") returns "translate(297.5)".
I am confused about whether it is 'x' or 'y'. Because I am using 'x' and 'y' values.
I am facing this problem in Internet Explorer (IE); however, it is working fine in other browsers.

have you considered not using internet explorer?

@JaromandaX I have to make it work in IE; the client insists.

OK - just a thought - you say it works in other browsers, but not in IE, and you are confused if "it is x or y" - surely it's the same thing as it is in the browsers that work?

JaromandaX Other browser always returns two values not matter what. Like translate(x,y)

Following worked for me.
var transformList = d3.select(me.svg.selectAll(".groupedbar")[0][0]).node().transform.baseVal;
var x, y;

// Loop through the transformations to find translate
for (var i = 0; i < transformList.numberOfItems; i++) {
    var transform = transformList.getItem(i);
    if (transform.type === SVGTransform.SVG_TRANSFORM_TRANSLATE) {
        x = transform.matrix.e;
        y = transform.matrix.f;
        break;
    }
}

console.log("x:", x, "y:", y);

